# Jboss 6 Class cast exception

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

When i deploy an ear for our project in Jboss 6.0.0.Final I am getting the error given below

is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.reflect.spi.NumberInfo cannot be cast to org.jboss.reflect.plugins.ClassInfoImpl
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1228) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:905) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:87) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.checkAllComplete(ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.java:107) [:0.2.2]

It works fine in Jboss 5.0.1GA, any help?